# How to generate code for a json file (with its data) at compile time?

Tags: c#, json, .net, code-generation

Imagine, there is a large json file with data. These data will never change for that version of the software. This is my file data.json:

```
{
    coordinates: [
        {x: 1, y: 2},
        {x: 2, y: 23},
        {x: 213, y: 82},
        {x: 41, y: 22},
        // ....
    ]
}
```

When we want to use that file, we could deserialize its data during runtime.

But that's kind of wasted time because we'd do this work on every application start (opening the file, reading the content, deserializing it, ...) instead of just once.

Is it somehow possible to use a "code generator" to do this at compile time, or even before?
"before" means: You can already save a .settings file in VS and it modifies the App.config file automatically then. Would it be possible to generate a .cs file if the json file as soon as someone saves it or builds the project?

This is what I expect as a result: A file Data.cs:

```
public class Data{
    public Coordinate[] Coordinates {
        get => new Coordinate[]{
            new (1,2),
            new (2,23),
            new (213,82),
            new (41,22),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: of course possible. but your reason is not appealing to me. loading the IL into memory still takes some time, right?

Comment: If you really want to and you're using a version of c# that has source generators, use them. You'd have to create at least a partial class that's empty, mark it with an attribute then let the source generator do its thing. Older versions there are code gen tools like T4 templates. But in all honesty, just read it at runtime.. Everyone does it with config values :D

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview

Answer (score 1):

There is an online tools that converts JSON to C# called [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/), which you can get packaged as a Visual Studio Code [Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype). Not only does it convert JSON to C#, but also to TypeScript, Python, Go, Ruby, Java, Swift, Rust, Kotlin, C++, Flow, Objective-C, JavaScript, Elm, and JSON Schema.

It's not exactly what you are asking for, but achieves the objective of statically translating JSON to code.

Comment: This does only create the structures at compile time. What I was looking for is literally some kind of generator that offers also THE DATA themselves via C# (see my code examples above).

Answer (score -1):

Json file usually keeps  a json version of data. If you want to have data in a compile time you  will have to keep it in .cs file as a  string constant.  There are lot of online utilities or it is easy to write your own to convert json to string. This is what you only need. But I can't see where do you take the json. Maybe it would be easier to create a text from the beginning? Especially your text that an array of short strings basically.

But I am not sure that will save time significantly

```
//ConstCoordianates.cs
public static class ConstCoordianates
{

public static ReadOnlyCollection<Coordinate> coordinates { get; set; } = 
new ReadOnlyCollection<Coordinate>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>
(Coordinates).Coordinates);

    public const string Coordinates = @"{
    ""coordinates"": [{
            ""x"": 1,
            ""y"": 2
        },
        {
            ""x"": 2,
            ""y"": 3
        }
    ]
    }";
}
```

classes

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("coordinates")]
    public List<Coordinate> Coordinates { get; set; }
}

public partial class Coordinate
{
    [JsonProperty("x")]
    public long X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("y")]
    public long Y { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to achieve. My idea is similar to https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32 . With that project of Microsoft: You create a txt file (here a JSON), save it and it generates you a lot of Win32 wrapper code (here a C# file that represents the content of the JSON file).

Comment: @ndsvw What wrapper code do you need  here?